# 301 redirection from thousands pages to single

Tags: seo, google-search-console, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I have a tech blog (CCTLD) running from 9 years with thousands of pages (including tags and categories) and i no longer want to continue that blog. And want to get benefit of its SEO value.

Now i have a another website (.com) which is a single page layout for my business.

I am thinking to redirect that blog which has almost similar keywords and thousands of organic link juice to my single business page.

My question - is it ok to use wildcard 301 redirection to redirect those thousands of pages to my new single page website?

I know in terms of user experience, it's not a good practice but there is no use of keeping that site alive any more. Better i can get some link juice for my business and which might help in SEO in a long run.

Also, i can't create hundreds of pages just for the shake of user experience and SEO and redirect each of them to my new business. That won't be relevant to my business.

Just want to hear SEO experts opinion in this situation.

Comment: Is your old site basically going away?? If so, then I would just to a blanket 301 redirect to the home page of the new site. Whether this will hurt or not really depends upon factors one you already covered. Personally, I would only consider doing this for a period before deleting the old domain. But not too long. My stronger alternative would be to just let the old domain die and focus on the new domain. Sometimes you just have to let an old site go and forget it. I have said goodbye to quite a few domains without regret. (except that I liked them)

Comment: I am not going to delete old domain as it carries high SEO value. It's not being updated from almost two years, so i am thinking to get benefit from that one in my new business. I hope that will give some juice to my new domain.

Comment: I am not sure what the best advice is. I would have to think about this.

Comment: I think that is bad. Mass redirecting 1000s of pages to a new website without having 301 domain level redirect.

Comment: Is your new/business site literally just a single page - one URL - or do you have different sections indicated with a fragment identifier?

Comment: @w3dk it's not exactly single page. It has different sections likes #services #about and one blog page where i write about new tech stuff. In total i have around 15 pages.

Answer (score 3):

301 redirection is a suggested method if you have almost similar content on the page you are redirecting to. Otherwise **google penalizes that and considers that a soft 404**, where-in the site is misleading the users.

So you can redirect some urls i.e. **apple-to-apple mapping**, but don't redirect everything to a single home page. Rather add a 410 permanently discontinued status on those pages.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting lot of pages which is having good SEO value to a single page website may not be a good idea. Consequently you lose SEO value for the old website. IMO Just use the website for advertising purpose of new website. Place a good banner. Offer something..

Comment: I liked you advertising concept. My main point was to transfer the link juice from old site to new. I found that homepage has good PA but other pages are not so good. So, i think the best thing is to just redirect homepage for now which has good link juice and good DA, PA and leave other pages as they are in old domain. What do you say?

Comment: If your blog content and new business website content is very much similar, you can create a sub folder in new business site for the blog and let search engines know that you have moved.Hopefully  ALL the DA & PA will be given to new website.